# Speed up ionic 2 live reload process

Tags: ionic2

Is there anyway to speed up the live reload process in ionic 2 after a save. Every save takes up to 10 to 15 seconds to show the changes, which is close to unbearable. Surely it should not take that long?

Comment: Hope you can put it here: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/new

Comment: not sure what i am doing wrong but the submit button is always disabled

Comment: did you put a Title?